# javascript prototype...is not afunction

Tags: javascript

i always get the error that player.draw() is not a function but i can't find the problem. The Player class exists, but not the draw method :( Wish i could give you more details, but there are not more. Thanks for your help, here is the code:

```
var version = "0.0.1";
var is_playing = false;

init();
function init(){
    background_canvas = document.getElementById("background-canvas");
    background_ctx = background_canvas.getContext("2d");
    main_canvas = document.getElementById("main-canvas");
    main_ctx = main_canvas.getContext("2d");

    requestaframe = (function(){
        return  window.requestAnimationFrame            ||
                window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame      ||
                window.mozRequestAnimationFrame         ||
                window.oRequestAnimationFrame           ||
                window.msRequestAnimationFrame          ||
                function(callback){ window.setTimeout(callback, 1000/60); };
    })();

    player = new Player();
    start_loop();
}

function mouse(e){
    var x = e.pageX - document.getElementById("game-holder").offsetLeft;
    var y = e.pageY - document.getElementById("game-holder").offsetTop;
    document.getElementById("x").innerHTML = x;
    document.getElementById("y").innerHTML = y;
}

function Player(){
    this.color = "yellow";
}

Player.prototype.draw = function(){
    main_ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
    main_ctx.arc(205, 70, 25, 0, 2*Math.PI);
    main_ctx.fill();    
};

function clearStage(){
    main_ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 800, 600);
}

function start_loop(){ is_playing = true; loop(); }
function stop_loop(){ is_playing = false; }

function loop(){
    clearStage();
    main_ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
    main_ctx.fillRect(175, 100, 450, 450);
    player.draw();
    if(is_playing) requestaframe(loop);
}
```

Comment: Share your Player Class.

Comment: where is the var `player` defined ?

Comment: you should place your `init();` in the end of your script.

Comment: Your functions get hoisted to the top of the scope, but not assignments like `Player.prototype.draw = function ...` So basically the prototype of `Player` is not modified the first time your loop runs.

Comment: @Sirko I think with a bit more explanation that's the answer rather than a comment.

Comment: Print player object in console before start_loop call and inspect the player object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to use hoisting, but do not seem to have understood it completely.

In general hoisting moves functions and variable declarations (not assignments!) to the top of the current scope. That's the reason, why you can call your `init()` method, before you actually declare it.

So stripping your code down a little, it looks like this

```
init();
function init() { ... }

function Player() { ... }

Player.prototype.draw = ...;
```

After hoisting (so the way your code is evaluated) it looks like this:

```
function init() { ... }

function Player() { ... }

init();

Player.prototype.draw = ...;
```

So you can clearly see, when you first call `init()` the `draw()` method has not been attached to the `Player` prototype, hence it is undefined.

Simple solution is to change  the order of your code and move the `init()` call to the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Function declarations are processed before code execution begins, so you can call *init* before its declaration:

```
init();
function init(){...}
```

Assignments happen later, during code execution, so the assignment:

```
Player.prototype.draw = function(){...}
```

hasn't occurred when you call *init* and hence *Player.prototype.draw* is undefined when you call *init*.

Move the call to the bottom of the script, or at least below all assignments to *Player.prototype*.